# Permalinks vs. duplicate merging

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Suppose that I link (offsite) to an answer that I gave to a question that was later closed as a duplicate, e.g. as I just did to my [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21007/given-2-numbers-a-and-b-what-is-the-maximum-number-which-can-not-be-formed-using/21032#21032). Suppose that my answer is later merged into the original (non-dup) question. Will my offsite link to my answer to the dup question no longer work? What is the proper way to link to avoid this problem? Or perhaps there is no problem since the new mods do not seem to be merging duplicates? Please advise since link rot is highly undesirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reading of http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/ is that your original link will either now point to a stub page that has a link to the merged question, or it will just work.

Comment: Thanks much, that's reassuring. Regarding permalinks, is it always safe to delete everything after the question number in the url?

Comment: @Bill: If you just want a link to the question, yes, I believe so, and I believe you can even shorten "question" to "q" (based on [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/)).

Answer (score 4):

If the merged question stub is deleted, it will auto-redirect to the target question.

Otherwise, there is always a link to the merged question in the stub.